# Shrink height of website to be mobile friendly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Website that I am working on. Before I get too far (yes most of the links don't work because I haven't made them yet) I am trying to make sure it fits on iPhones and other mobile devices. The height (CSS) works great on a computer, but it extends far below what I intend when loaded on a mobile device.

Here is the script of my index.html page:

```
html body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0%;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        background-image: url(http://www.jpegchaos.com/chipimage.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    #fullbody {
        margin: 0px;
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
    }
    #left {
        width: 15%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        display: inline-block;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    #center {
        width: 70%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        background-color: lightgrey;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #centertextarea {
        width: 90%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0px;
        margin-right: 5%;
        margin-left: 5%;
        margin-top: 0px;
        text-wrap: normal;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    #right {
        width: 15%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .header {
        font-size: 40px;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .footer{
        background-color: lightgrey;
        font-size: 13px;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        bottom: -60px;
        height: 100px;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 60%;
        margin-left: 20%;
    }
```

then the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name=viewport content='width=700'>
        <title>JPeG & Chaos LLP - Your Technology Repair HQ</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/structure.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/advanced.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/tags.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-1/c27.0.160.160/p160x160/541649_1552490621690166_7622307717201533155_n.jpg?oh=0be92daed3243de2719efe5185583bc1&oe=55D3880B&__gda__=1437242841_f81d654a074a10e951f604fd343220c9">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#top").load("structure/header.html");
                $("#bottom").load("structure/footer.html");
                $("#menubar").load("structure/menubar.html");
                $("#newssidebar").load("news.html");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fullbody">
            <div id="left"></div>
            <div id="center">
                <div id="top"></div>
                <div id="menubar"></div>
                <div id="centertextarea">
                    <table class="noborder">
                        <tr class="noborder">
                            <td class="splitleft">
                                <!-- Removed for Clerity -->
                            </td>
                            <td class="hollowmiddle"></td>
                            <td class="splitright">
                                <!-- Removed for Clerity -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <div id="bottom"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="right">
                <div id="newssidebar"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The frames and everything load perfectly, but the center one seems to go WAY too far.

I took out the "footer" div and it's still too tall, so excluding that from the possibility list.

Comment: In Chrome, there is a 'Device mode' in the developer tools (smartphone/tablet icon next to the 'Elements' tab), which you can use to simulate devices. FireFox has a similar feature. Maybe it's helpful to test your page there, because you can actually inspect the elements and check which CSS rules are applied.

Comment: @GolezTrol thank you for that. I'll def use that going forward.

Comment: What if they view the website in landscape view on their phone? That's really tiny. Why do you need to constrain the height in this way?

Comment: my original goal way back when I started this was to have a footer at the bottom of the viewable page. Since originally I had no need to worry about content overflowing, I set `overflow: hidden;` and stuck the footer to the bottom. I'm beginning to think I may want to pixilate the distances instead of % them...

Comment: The nature of web design is for the content to expand vertically as more content is added. You can still Have a sticky footer, and have the content `overflow-y:auto` to make it scroll able when it is too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throught many changes, and the comments I received I did the following to fix this:

*removed height function from the `#right` div
*changed `#left` div to `height: 1px;`
*changed `#center` div to `height: 100vh`
*added `overflow-y: auto;` to the `#center` div
*changed `#footer` to:

```
.footer{
    background-color: lightgrey;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```